# require expert opinion in making a stack

Tags: python, stack

I started programming 2 weeks ago and after watching youtube video about a stack(honestly i barely know what it is) i tried making a program which adds an element into a stack? and then checks whether that element already exists or not, but i am faced with an issue that no mater what it always says "this element already exists" please help!!

```
stack = []

for i in range(1):
    init_element =  int(input(f"enter element {i} : "))
    stack.append(init_element)
    
for n in range(9):
    elements = int(input(f"enter elements : "))
    for elements in stack:
        for x in range(9):
            if elements == stack[x]:
                print("this element already exists in stack!")
                break
            if elements != stack[x]:
                stack.append(elements)
print(stack)
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the same variable name to get user input and to iterate over a list. That's why the element always exists.

The issue is in these lines of code

```
    elements = int(input(f"enter elements : "))
    for elements in stack:
```

notice how **elements** is used for both user input and list iteration.

Comment: tried changing the name and it was just an infinite loop anyways thanks alot, i was using the for loop wrong i still dont understand that well. thank you